# PowerShell 365 - Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks convert value error

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm trying to clear the membership of a 365 group but the remove command doesn't accept wildcards, so have opted to use a 'get-user' and put it into a 'foreach'. However this errors. Can you help?

```
#get list
$users = Get-UnifiedGroupLinks –Identity "testgroup" -LinkType Members
#empty list
    foreach($user in $users){
        Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks –Identity "testgroup" –LinkType "Members" –Links $user
    }
```

error

```
Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Links'. Cannot convert value "System.Collections.ArrayList" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter[]". Error: "Cannot 
convert the "Mr User" value of type "Deserialized.Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Management.ReducedRecipient" to type "Microsoft.Exchange.Configuration.Tasks.RecipientIdParameter"."
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks], ParameterBindin...mationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks
    + PSComputerName        : outlook.office365.com
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Links` parameter on [Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/remove-unifiedgrouplinks?view=exchange-ps) specifies the user(s) to remove from the Microsoft 365 Group.
It needs a value that uniquely identifies the recipient and for that you can use any of these:

- Name
- Alias
- Distinguished name (DN)
- Canonical DN
- Email address
- GUID

In your code, you need to select only such a property from the member objects as they are returned by `Get-UnifiedGroupLinks`, like the users Email address.

Try

```
#get list
$users = (Get-UnifiedGroupLinks –Identity "testgroup" -LinkType Members).PrimarySMTPAddress
#empty list
foreach($user in $users){
    Remove-UnifiedGroupLinks –Identity "testgroup" –LinkType Members –Links $user
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer would work, but another way to do it would be to specify the user in a different way "on the fly" inside the foreach loop. Since you used Get-UnifiedGroupLinks to pull in the user objects, you pulled back lots of properties in your $users variable that you can work with. You just need to be more specific inside your foreach loop, and use one of those properties.

You can specify the **PrimarySmtpAddress** for each user inside your foreach loop like this:

```
    –Links $($user).PrimarySmtpAddress
```

I have been working on some code samples for managing Teams/unified groups and used this technique inside of some foreach loops: [Unsubscribe-FollowInInbox.ps1](https://gist.github.com/larspassic/430fd6558be4ec1fba29aae36c03db0f)

Let me know if you have any questions!